# router navigate not working inside a subscribe (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing the following problem:

Im call my getByUsernameandPassword method and I recieve a response, but when I try to redirect the user to the /zeiterfassung route it just shows me the same /login page.. I wrote a console.log() to check if its entering in the res, and it does.. can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Component:

```
  public async anmelden() {
    this.loading = true;
    this._benutzerservice.getByUsernameAndPassword(this.benutzerFormControl.value, this.passwortFormControl.value)pipe(first()).subscribe(
      res =>  {
        this._router.navigate(['/zeiterfassung']);
      },
      err => {
        console.log("a");
      });
```

Comment: Have you sorted this issue ? Can you share your solution please.

Answer (score 1):

for solving this issue I did the following:

1. create a function that return promise after observable complete
2. create another function that call *first function* which will wait
   promise to resolve.
3. after promise get resolved you can navigate successfully.

```
  isObservableCompleted(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.observable$.pipe(takeWhile("put your condition to make observable 
        complete")
    , finalize(() => {
          resolve(true);
        })).subscribe();
      
    })

  }

  async routeAfterComplete(){
    let isComplete = await this.isObservableCompleted();
    if(isComplete)
      this._router.navigate([]) // here you can navigate successfully
  }
```

> it's just a workaround but it works

Answer (score 0):

by default navigate method will try to navigate to yourdomain.com/zeiterfassung

by following way it will navigate to current URL e.g. yourcurenturl/zeiterfassung

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route :ActivatedRoute) 

public async anmelden() {
    this.loading = true;
    this._benutzerservice.getByUsernameAndPassword(this.benutzerFormControl.value, this.passwortFormControl.value)pipe(first()).subscribe(
      res =>  {
        this._router.navigate(['zeiterfassung'],{relativeTo:this.route});
      },
      err => {
        console.log("a");
      });
```

Comment: I actually wanna change from localhost:4200/login to localhost:4200/zeiterfassung